# Is there another way to exclude folders in Homestead rather than using rsync?

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Laravel Homestead as my local development environment on my Linux machine, and learned about excluding folders, which is great to avoid syncing Symfony's cache.

Currently I'm using rsync, with this configuration:

```yaml
folders:
    - map: ~/www/my-symfony-project
      to: /home/vagrant/www/my-symfony-project
      type: "rsync"
      options:
          rsync__exclude: ["var/cache"]
```

I then have to run `vagrant rsync-auto` from my Homestead directory in order to initiate rsync and get file sync to work.

I was wondering, is there any other way besides rsync to have this feature and not having to run `rsync-auto` every time I need to boot up my Homestead VM?